# angularjs UI.Ace directive JSON worker error messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ace-editor

I am using the angularjs UI.Ace directive (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace) and I set the mode to 'json'. Now I'm getting the error icon in the gutter but when hovering over it there's no text hint about the error. Aren't these hints provided by the worker-json? Could it be that I'm missing a certain option?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Please set value on "hello"
- if you are using some editer(IDE) and if your code is working fine so please ignore this kind of error.

Comment: The problem is not the error icon - that is intentional - but I would like to see a hint text when hovering over the icon like e.g. `Unexpected '}'`.